# What is the link between free energy and lagrangian?

Tags: thermodynamics, lagrangian-formalism, energy

[Free energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy) is a generalization of energy when the system exchanges heat with the environment. Energy, in its turn, can be extracted from lagrangian under the symmetry of time $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0)$. However, I can't find any sources that links the free energy directly from lagrangian. Is there any way to do that? If it is, what symmetry is it based on?

Comment: If you like this Phys.SE question, you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51534/2451) Phys.SE post.