# What kind of conservation law is energy conservation in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, noethers-theorem

As I understand it, Noether's theorem is an important result that allows us to show when certain kinds of conservations arise. Is energy conservation in thermodynamics a result of Noether's theorem? If not, where does it come from? Or is it just an accepted axiom?

Comment: Energy conservation in thermodynamics is expressed by the first law, which declares heat to be a form of (internal) energy that obeys energy conservation. From a statistical mechanics point of view this is a trivial consequence of energy conservation on the microscopic level. On some level the beauty of thermodynamics lies in the very fact that such a microscopic explanation for its axioms is not necessary. It works perfectly without it.

Comment: Note that Noether's theorem relies on a Lagrangian formulation, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51534/2451) Phys.SE post.