# Lagrange Equation for thermal system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, thermal-conductivity

I am working on modeling of a multi-physical system using Lagrange based modeling and we know that Lagrange function, $L$, can be defined as below;
$L= T-V$
where:
$T=$Kinetic Energy
$V=$Potential Energy

Now my query is how to define Kinetic energy and potential energy for a thermal system in terms of $T$ and $V$, so one can put it into Lagrange function and also how to define generalized forces in the thermal system for Lagrange equation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51534/2451 and links therein.

Comment: By thermal system you mean, for example, a gas of free-floating particles that collides elastically? There are 3 generalized coordinates per particle in that setup. If you have 10 particles that means 30 differential equations to solve (Lagrange's equations).

Comment: This might be related: [A Lagrangian Description of Thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6152).

Comment: I mean for conduction in solids. i.e for heating polymer inside the barrel, heaters are installed. so now to study the conduction I want to use Lagrange equation.