# Symmetry principles and analogous Noether's theorem for stochastic systems

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, variational-principle, noethers-theorem, stochastic-processes

In the case of Newtonian mechanics, taking a variational or Lagrangian or Maximum principle (MP) view, one can obtain the conservation laws (energy, linear momentum and angular momentum) by combining the MP with the symmetry principles (time, linear displacement and angular displacement). This is a key contribution by [Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

The [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) or the Master equation (called Liouville in the case of deterministic dynamics) governs density evolution of an Ito  stochastic process. The intuition behind obtaining this mathematical description is the principle of the conservation of mass combined with a minimum principle. This was shown by Nelson in the work on the [derivation of the Schrodinger equation from Newtonian mechanics](http://www.physics.utah.edu/%7Elebohec/ScaleRelativity/Papers/1966_ENelson_Derivation_of_SchrodEq_from_NewtMech.pdf).

> Is it possible to combine other types of symmetry principles (time,
> linear displacement and angular displacement) to obtain *stochastic
> versions* of the laws of conservation of *stochastic* energy, linear
> and angular momenta?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Note that Noether's theorem relies on a Lagrangian formulation, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51534/2451) Phys.SE post.