What type of energy do all processes in the world tend toward? What does the principle of least action have to do with entropy?
As we know the sum of kinetic and potential energy in a system is constant. For example, we can take an ideal pendulum, in which kinetic energy can change into potential energy and back again for a long time. On the other hand we know that atoms, molecules, and objects on Earth tend to move to the state of minimum potential energy. On the third hand we know that man and our inventions tend to feed on “ordered” energy, and it becomes more chaotic in the course of entropy (but we believe that the Earth is an isolated system from a thermodynamic point of view). We also know that in classical mechanics objects move based on the principle of least action (action is related to the integral of potential and kinetic energy ratios). The question arises, how does the principle of least action relate to entropy? Will objects tend to move more chaotically as a result of the solution of finding the path of an object (using the principle of minimum action)? To what kind of energy does the evolution of the Universe tend to move as a result of entropy? Is it kinetic or potential energy?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47581/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483580/2451 and links therein.
